# Trying to update a subdocument in a parent document mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am trying to update or remove a subdocument from a parent document using mongoose.

My code:

```
editSubscription(req, res) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    jwt.verify(token, req.app.get('yourSecretKey'), function (err, payload) {
        userModel.update({ _id: payload.user._id, "subscriptions._id": req.params.id }, { "$set": { "subscriptions.$": req.body } }, function (err, obj) {
           console.log(obj)
       })
    })
}
```

The output of the console.log is

```
{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

How should i do this? i know if its modified the nModified returns a 1. I can't find any docs on how to approach this or solve it and all the solutions here on stackoverflow i already tried, nothing is working.

A sample of a document in my collection:

```
id: '5db990daa05aa90de0c8b86b',
user:
{ role: 'User',
 subscriptions: [ 
  { active: true,
_id: '5dbad05aaf232e2bdc033339',
name: 'Basic Fit',
price: 20,
paymentDate: '07-11-2020',
created: '2019-10-31T12:15:22.360Z',
updated: '2019-10-31T12:15:22.360Z' },
{ active: true,
_id: '5dbad2568bf56255a0f39bc7',
name: 'Netflix',
price: 10,
paymentDate: '07-11-2019',
created: '2019-10-31T12:23:50.141Z',
updated: '2019-10-31T12:23:50.141Z' } ]
  ],
 _id: '5db990daa05aa90de0c8b86b',
 fullname: 'Test naam',
 email: 'test1@mail.com',
 password:
  '$2a$10$VzBnIcVraIRdmzy6rPHOX.7gGOXToTBNISLEfi429OfpRx02FxCaO',
 birthDate: '02-12-1988',
 created: '2019-10-30T13:32:10.276Z',
 updated: '2019-10-30T13:32:10.276Z',
 __v: 0 },
```

payload.user._id == the verified logged in user ID

req.params.id is supposed to be the subscriptionId im trying to edit

Comment: Can you post a sample document from your collection?       What are the values of "payload.user._id" and "req.params.id"?

Comment: @Haruo i edited my post..

Comment: I asked for the values of "payload.user._id" and "req.params.id" so I could know the type of them.
In your documents, "_id" and "subscriptions._id" are of what type? String or ObjectId?

Comment: ObjectId @Haruo

Comment: Post your code when you define/set the values of "req.params.id" and "payload.user._id", please.

Comment: payload.user._id im getting from req.headers.authorization.. and req.params.id im getting from the url when i do the request

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
editSubscription(req, res) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    jwt.verify(token, req.app.get('yourSecretKey'), function (err, payload) {
        userModel.update({ _id: ObjectId(payload.user._id), "subscriptions._id": ObjectId(req.params.id) }, { "$set": { "subscriptions.$": req.body } }, function (err, obj) {
           console.log(obj)
       })
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried and im getting a 500 error response back..

When i remove the 'req.params.id' and i do it like this:

```
userModel.updateOne({ _id: payload.user._id }, { "$set": { "subscriptions.0.price": 
req.body.price} }).then(user => {
           console.log(user)
        }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err)
       })
```

Then it works but since i have multiple items in an array i do not want to update only the first one..

I tried using a filter in the $set operator but im getting errors all over the place..